# jQuery Validate all fields remotely

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I do not accept any HTML in my PHP application so I intend to block anything submitted with HTML tags. I attempted to add the following JavaScript to add additional jQuery Validate rules to all text input fields.

I'm using WordPress Ajax so action and url are submitted together.

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        remote:  {
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'ad_sanitize',
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The above js returns error in Firefox console

> TypeError: a.data(...) is undefined ...ar d,e,f,g,h,i,j=this[0] if(b)switch(d=a.data(j.form,"validator").settings,e=d.r... in Jquery,js

```
  $('#formname').validate({

    rules: {
       field1: 'required',
       field2: 'required',
    },
    message: {
       field1: 'Required',
       field2: 'Required'
   }
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        console.log('done');
   });
```

The above action will point to the following function serverside

```
function isHtml($string) //This function just checks for html
{
    if ( $string != strip_tags($string) )
    {
        return true; // Contains HTML
    }
    return false; // Does not contain HTML
}

function ad_sanitize () { //<- This function calls when ajax call (Tested)

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isHtml($value) === true) {
            echo 'Only plain text allowed.';
        } else {
            echo true;
        }

    }
}
```

**Problem:** When I added the above JavaScript, my jQuery Validate will not work anymore (form submitted without validating), and of course, the remote check is not called.

Comment: Pay attention to your JavaScript console errors.

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem**: When I added the above JavaScript, my jQuery Validate will not work anymore (form submitted without validating), and of course, the remote check is not called.

That's because you've broken your JavaScript with some syntax issues that should be triggering JavaScript console errors:

- You've misspelled the `messages` object as `message`.
- You're missing a comma after your `messages` object.
- You're missing a closing `}` brace for the `submitHandler` function.

---

```
$('#formname').validate({
    rules: {
        field1: 'required',
        field2: 'required',
    },
    messages: {   // <- "messages" was misspelled here
        field1: 'Required',
        field2: 'Required'
    },   // <- comma was missing from here
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        console.log('done');
    }    // <- closing brace was missing from here
});
```

---

As far as your server-side code:

[Per `remote` documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), the response from the server **must** be a JSON string.  The `remote` method **absolutely will not work** if you do not echo the response as a JSON encoded string.

```
function ad_sanitize () {

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isHtml($value) === true) {
            echo json_encode("Only plain text allowed."); // fail validation using this message
        } else {
            echo json_encode("true"); // pass validation
            // echo "true";  // also works the same (notice the quotes)
        }
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT**:  Following the example for `data` in [the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), use a function...

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        remote:  {
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: function() {
                    return 'ad_sanitize';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank u, the syntaxes were right on my codes but probably errored when i type here. Anyway can u check my updated question? I think something wrogn with adding new rules. That part itself returns jquery error, without that part my whole js and ajaxes all working fine.

Comment: @DaveTeu, see my updated answer.  You might need a function inside `data`.

Comment: @DaveTeu, the `remote` method absolutely will not work if you do not echo the response as a JSON encoded string.

Comment: @DaveTeu, also please be more careful when posting code in the future.  Everyone's time is wasted on your typing errors instead of solving the real problem.

Comment: I've posted the real problem, problem is the ajax did not even post to my server side php. Jquery validate did not read the extra rules. according to wordpress admin-ajax.php, the attribute 'action' has to point to my function in my php file. I didn't see the remote working when i click form submit.

Comment: @DaveTeu, the `data` option of ajax does not define the `action` attribute... it only sends additional data as part of the query string. Refer to the documentation for an explanation of `data`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax  The `action` attribute is normally part of the form tag, but in the case of `.ajax()`, **the `url` is the action**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#userForm").validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                conform_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                gender: {
                    required: true
                },
                "hobby[]": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                },
                address: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                country_id: {
                    required: true
                },
                state_id: {
                    required: true
                },
                image: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "please valid enter name"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "please valid email"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "the password is required"
                },
                conform_password: {
                    required: "this conform password is required",
                    equalTo: "please enter same password"
                },
                gender: {
                    required: "please select your gender"
                },
                "hobby[]": {
                    required: "please select your hobby"
                },
                address: {
                    required: "please Enter your address",
                    minlength: "minimum 10 character"
                },
                country_id: {
                    required: "please select one country"
                },
                state_id: {
                    required: "please select one state"
                },
                image: {
                    required: "please select your image"
                }
            },

            submitHandler: function(userForm) {
                userForm.insert();
            }

        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#name").keypress(function(event) {
            var inputValue = event.charCode;
            if (!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<h2>User Register Form</h2>

<form id="userForm" name="userForm" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name : </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email : </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password : </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="conform_password">Conform Password : </label>
            <input type="password" name="conform_password" id="conform_password" placeholder="Enter Your Conform Password">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender" class="radio-inline gender"><b class="gender">Gender : </b>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male">&nbsp; &nbsp;Male
            </label>
            <label for="gender" class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="Female">&nbsp; &nbsp;Female
            </label>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="hobby" class="checkbox-inline"><b class="hobbies"> Hobby : </b>
                <input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="hobby[]" id="cricket" value="cricket">&nbsp; &nbsp;Cricket
            </label>
            <label for="hobby" class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" value="hockey" name="hobby[]" id="hockey">&nbsp; &nbsp;Hockey
            </label>
            <label for="hobby" class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" value="horserace" name="hobby[]" id="horserace">&nbsp; &nbsp;Horse Race
            </label>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address : </label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="address" rows="3" name="address"></textarea>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country_id">Select Country : </label>
            <select name="country_id" id="country_id">
                <option value="India">--select country--</option>
                <option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="India">USA</option>
                <option value="India">Rusia</option>

            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="state_id">Select State : </label>
            <select id="state_id" name="state_id">
                <option value="">--select state--</option>
                <option value="">rajasthan</option>
                <option value="">gujarat</option>
                <option value="">kerla</option>
            </select>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" size="20" />

        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="insert" value="submit" name="insert">Add Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="country_id"]').on('change', function() {
            var countryId = $(this).val();
            if (countryId) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Crud/fetch_state/" + countryId,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        country_id: countryId
                    },

                    success: function(data) {

                        $('select[name="state_id"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="state_id"]').append('<option value="' + value.state_id + '">' + value.state_name + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('select[name="state_id"]').empty();
            }
        });`enter code here`
    });
</script>
```